# Is there any way to redirect download stream request directly instead downloading file twice (by server and then by user)?

Tags: php, download, stream, microservices

I have an url to a microservice, like `api.service.com/generateRandomPdf` that downloads an X file.

I wish to use this URL in my backend server in PHP application in a way that the file from given URL is directly passed to client without storing downloaded file in some `/tmp` directory so the call to `mysite.com/download` would be equivalent in logic to `api.service.com/generateRandomPdf`. In other words - I don't want to download the file twice

I think I could make it by using `.htaccess` or any rewrite rules, but I also need to set some auth tokens in that request and the whole code has a character of composer package which kind of limits me I suppose.

Comment: I think this can be achieved with file_get_contents

Comment: I think you want [readfile](https://www.php.net/readfile).

Comment: I allow users to upload their files, but rename their files into sha256 the moment upload finishes. I store original file name, owner's info and hash of the file in database. All files are given back to clients using 'give.php' script that checks permission for file access, generates headers and executes `readfile($hash)`. If you are dealing with complicated file permissions, group policies or anything of similar nature, I suggest not limiting yourself to .htaccess

Comment: I wonder whether you use nginx. Take a look at [Custom handler in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59458463/12396017) to do exactly what you need. This way php will not read file at all

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny this is exactly what I want to achieve but I am writing wordpress plugin so... It may be apache, or nginx, or apache behind nginx... hard to tell.

Comment: then ```readfile``` is your only friend if you need to check access permissions for the user

Comment: Ok thank you. I will remove the file from server anyway